# Убрать дубликаты по нескольким столбцам MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как проверить и убрать дубли по нескольким столбцам, заменив их на NULL
Пример:

```
1   2050    2030    2050
2   2040    2030    2050
3   2020    2020    2000
4   2015    2015    2000
```

Должно быть:

```
1   2050    2030    NULL
2   2040    NULL    NULL
3   2020    NULL    2000
4   2015    NULL    NULL
```

Колонок может быть неограниченное кол-во
Заранее признателен

Comment: Опишите логику поиска дубликатов более подробно, я сколько ни смотрел на представленные данные - не смог понять, какие закономерности вы видите. Если в строке не должно быть дубликатов чисел, то первая строка понятна (2050 встретилось два раза, второе зануляем), но тогда не понятна вторая стока, там все числа уникальны. Если искать дубликаты по отдельным столбцам, то первый столбец понятен, второй - нет. На диагоналях искать не стал, кажется не это вы имели ввиду.

Comment: В текущей постановке вопроса - никак. Во-первых, вообще непонятно, что Вы назвали "дублями". Во-вторых, даже если есть некий дубль, нет критерия,  по которому однозначно понятно, какой оставить. а какой обNULLитью

Comment: Предположим есть поля ID, Number1,Number2,Number3
ID уникальные, а number могут быть заполнены как в темповую таблицу или в CTE.
Важно проверить как в самой строке 1,2,3 и далее на уникальность, так и по столбцу Number1,Number2,Number3. Если встречается дубликат, то заменяется на NULL

Comment: О господи, я нашёл систему. Нужно размотать всю таблицу в одномерный массив, потом для каждого числа заменить все вхождения кроме первого на нуль, потом обратно спроецировать данные на места. Т.е. 2050, 2030, 2050 (зануляем), продолжаем с начала второй стоки 2040, 2030 (было ранее, зануляем), 2050 (было ранее, зануляем), переходим на третью строку.... Не уверен, что правильно понял алгоритм, но приведённый пример полностью покрывается этим алгоритмом. Практичность задачи под вопросом, но можно сделать маленький кодгольф.

Comment: Если встречается предположим строка
1   2050    2030    2050
то оставляем один 2050, другие NULL
1   2050    2030    NULL

Comment: @AK, да вы всё правильно поняли. Только реализацию к сожалению сообразить сложно :(

Comment: *реализацию к сожалению сообразить сложно* Пока не озвучена СУБД - так и просто невозможно. Узнать версию я уж и не надеюсь... а вообще задачка несложная. Проще всего, наверное, решать в формате хранимой процедуры, используя временную таблицу.

Comment: Как по мне, задача разбивается на две: во-первых, нужно написать функцию, которая для текущего i того столбца и j той строки возвратит bool было ли ранее такое значение. Во-вторых, нужно просто пройти по порядку строки и столбцы применяя эту функцию для каждой ячейки. Для конкретики хорошо бы понимать какая у вас база, что бы знать, какие средства языка можно использовать. Или хочется на ANSI SQL 92 совместимое решение под любую базу данных?

Comment: @AK,@Akina использую Microsoft SQL Server 2012